# Error while using recycler view inside a fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am trying to use a recycler view inside my dashboard fragment but the app crashes when I try to run the app and shows this error in logcat window -> **Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference**

This is my fragment code

```java
package com.example.bookhub;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Dashboard_Fragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView Recycler;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    Dashboard_Recycler_Adapter recyclerAdapter;
    List<String> bookList = Arrays.asList(
            "P.S. I love You",
            "The Great Gatsby",
            "Anna Karenina",
            "Madame Bovary",
            "War & Peace",
            "Middlemarch",
            "The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn",
            "Moby-Dick",
            "The Lord of the Rings");

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Recycler = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Recycler);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        recyclerAdapter = new Dashboard_Recycler_Adapter((Context) getActivity(),bookList);

        Recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        Recycler.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
    }
}
```

This is the code for the adapter

```
package com.example.bookhub;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Dashboard_Recycler_Adapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<Dashboard_Recycler_Adapter.DashboardViewHolder>{

List<String> bookList;
public Dashboard_Recycler_Adapter(Context context, List<String> list)
{
    this.bookList = list;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public DashboardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_single_row, parent, false);
    return new DashboardViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DashboardViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    holder.textView.setText(bookList.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return bookList.size();
}

public static class DashboardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView textView;
    public DashboardViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtRecyclerRowItem);
    }
}
```

}

This is the XML Code of the recycler view in the dashboard fragment

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Dashboard_Fragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/dashboard_fragment"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/Recycler"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.088"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.075" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your layout has not been inflated and you are using it before. Means Layout creation is not completed and you are using it before that. Write your code in onViewCreated() method to get all component of layout.

You have placed your code in wrong method(). Remove below code from onCreatview().

```
Recycler = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Recycler);

layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

recyclerAdapter = new Dashboard_Recycler_Adapter((Context) 
getActivity(),bookList);

Recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
Recycler.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
```

Override onViewCreated() method in fragment and copy and paste above code into that.

After changes your fragment class would be look like below code.

```
public class Dashboard_Fragment extends Fragment {

public Dashboard_Fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup 
container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, 
container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle 
savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    Recycler = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Recycler);

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    recyclerAdapter = new Dashboard_Recycler_Adapter((Context) 
    getActivity(),bookList);

    Recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    Recycler.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);

   }
}
```

Comment: Bro could you just give me your no.? I am unable to solve the error, it would be very kind of you if i could get your help.

Comment: Bro i can't provide no. but you can ask me anything i will answer.

Comment: Look i have updated me answer and added code where you have made changes.

Comment: Oh my god bro! It worked and I'm really thankful for that.

Comment: Bhai actually maine abhi android development shuru kiya hai toh agar koi hoga jisse mai doubts puchh paau toh it'll be very helpful. Is there any way I can contact you? Any social media handle or anything? You may delete the comment later so that no one else could spam it. Please bhai.

Answer (score 0):

You should inflate the view before to get its RecyclerView.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Dashboard_Fragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recycler;
    
    Dashboard_Recycler_Adapter recyclerAdapter;
    List<String> books= Arrays.asList(
        "P.S. I love You",
        "The Great Gatsby",
        "Anna Karenina",
        "Madame Bovary",
        "War & Peace",
        "Middlemarch",
        "The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn",
        "Moby-Dick",
        "The Lord of the Rings");

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle 
        savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        recycler = view.findViewById(R.id.Recycler);

        recyclerAdapter = new Dashboard_Recycler_Adapter(requiredContext(), books);

        recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(requiredActivity()));
        recycler.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    }
}
```

Advices : you should name your classes in camel case format (DashboardFragment, DashboardRecyclerAdapter etc.).
In fragments use resquiredContext and requiredActivity when you wants context or activity.

Comment: Tried this but nothing happened, still the same

Comment: @ShresthaNand add your Code into onViewCreated() then it will work.

Comment: I tried to rename the onCreateView function to onViewCreated() and the app is running now but recycler view is not visible, fragment is totally empty..

Comment: Edited. onCreateView method is call before onViewCreated ans its role is to initialize the view (inflate the layout) and return it. onViewCreated role is to setUp the view that have been return by the onCreateView. it's good place to setUp the views.

Answer (score -1):

Change this line

```
RecyclerView Recycler;
```

to this

```
RecyclerView recycler;
```

and also this line

```
Recycler = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Recycler);
```

to this

```
recycler= getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Recycler);
```

Comment: Didnt solve the error.

Comment: where is your recyclerView? in fragment or activity?

Comment: if you are inflating recyclerView from fragment then you don't need to include `getActivity()` simply replace this with `view.findViewById()`

Comment: why would changing the casing of the variables do anything ? doesn't make sense

Comment: `Recycler` can't be used as a variable name because its a class and also he is making mistake by passing reference of activity while binding the view, he should be using `view.findViewById()` since the recyclerView is in fragment not in activity.